# How can I remove selected text and keep empty HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, text, range, selection

User makes a selection inside of an HTML code in a web browser (rendered html).

Then I need to remove the **text** from the selection but keep the **html tags**.

Selection example:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

I can get the range via `selection.getRangeAt(0)` and therefore access the start / end nodes. I think I need to loop through the nodes between the start / end nodes but I can't figure out how; the start/end nodes are not necessarily siblings and this complicates the algorithm...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to figure out right now? How to get the selected text, or how to strip the text?

Comment: @Spectric I'm trying to figure our how to strip the text :) I'm able to get the selected text. Not sure if it's the best approach but I can insert an html comment before and after the selection and then extract the selected html. However, it's not that helpful. I think I need to loop over the selected nodes somehow, check the node type and remove the text nodes...

Comment: What is the context here, a web browser? Are they selecting rendered html in the dom as in a web browser? Or are they selecting a section of unrendered raw HTML as they would in VS Code (monaco editor?) as Spectric believes. And if so what application are they doing this in?

Comment: @WillD They are selecting in a web browser (so it's a rendered html). I can get the range via selection.getRangeAt(0) and therefore access the start / end nodes. I think I need to loop over the nodes between start / end nodes but I can't figure out how; the start/end nodes are not necessarily siblings and this complicates the algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have a working version of this. And I have to say it was a fun, challenging puzzle.

Basically this utilizes the built in method [Selection.deleteFromDocument()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/deleteFromDocument) Which does almost what you want, the problem is that it also will destroy any elements that are caught up in the selection as it gets deleted. So to solve for this I:

- Assign every dom elemnt a sequential unique id as a `data-*` attribute.
- Keep a snapshot of the dom in an array from before the `.deleteFromDocument()` operation.
- Take another picture of the dom after the deletion operation and create a list of DOM nodes that were removed by the `.deleteFromDocument()` operation by comparing the two arrays.
- Then with the list of elements that got the knife, loop through these and add them back using the awareness of their parent or previous sibling nodes (which are still findable via their unique id which I gave them).
- Remove their `innerText` because they retained it from before the delete operation.
- Finally cleanup and remove the unique ids from all elements.

```js
   const button = document.querySelector("button");

      let uniqueIdNumber = 0;
      function uniqueId() {
        uniqueIdNumber++;
        return uniqueIdNumber;
      }

      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
        allElements.forEach((element) =>
          element.setAttribute("data-unique", uniqueId())
        );
        const originalDom = [...allElements].map((element) => ({
          element: element,
          uniqueId: element.getAttribute("data-unique"),
          parent: element.parentElement?.getAttribute("data-unique"),
          prev: element.previousElementSibling?.getAttribute("data-unique"),
        }));

        const selection = document.getSelection();
        selection.deleteFromDocument();

        const newAllElements = [...document.querySelectorAll("*")];
        const newDom = newAllElements.map((element) =>
          element.getAttribute("data-unique")
        );

        const removedElements = originalDom.filter(
          (x) => !newDom.find((y) => x.uniqueId === y)
        );

        removedElements.forEach((record) => {
          const prev =
            record.prev &&
            document.querySelector(`[data-unique="${record.prev}"]`);
          if (prev) {
            prev.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", record.element);
            record.element.innerText = "";
          } else {
            const parent = document.querySelector(
              `[data-unique="${record.parent}"]`
            );
            if (parent) {
              parent.prepend(record.element);
              record.element.innerText = "";
            }
          }
        });
      document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((element) => {
        element.removeAttribute("data-unique");
      });

    });
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>The quick</li>
  <li>brown fox</li>
  <li>something something</li>
  <li>the lazy dog</li>
</ul>

<button>Delete Selection</button>
```

Comment: What a great solution, you rock!! I only think that the last cleanup part should be inside the click handler. Also, It seems that it destroys the initial html formatting (Indentation and spacing) when you remove/re-insert the nodes. That's why I would prefer to loop through the nodes between the start and the end ones and only remove their InnerText. But again, your solution is great and definitely will help me a lot!!

Comment: Oh, yeah completely agree about cleanup inside the click callback. I meant to do that just mixed up the closing brackets.

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the content between the html tags and alter the html that way. So you are left with an empty `li`.

```js
items = document.querySelectorAll('li')

items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(){
            item.innerHTML = ''
        if (item===items[1]) {
            item.innerHTML = '<b></b>' // so 2nd still has the <b> tags
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div id='root'>
    <ul>
        <li>The quick</li>
        <li>brown <b>fox</b> jumps</li>
        <li>over the</li>
        <li>lazy dog</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution which only works for the specific sample code the OP provided.

Comment: This would work on any `li` element in the code.

Comment: I need a generic solution which will work for any html code / any selection :)